# Why doesn't jquery get input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, repeater

I have used an asp.net repeater to repeat images.

I want to get the primary key ID returned from the database upon clicking the image via jquery but it shows undefined. I am storing image in input text field and it's getting displayed in that but not in alert.

jQuery:

```
function displayStory() {
    var txtIDValue = $(this).find('input[id$=txtID]').val();
    var id = txtIDValue;
    alert(id);
}
```

Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrImages" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>    
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <input type="text" id="txtID" value='<%#Eval("ID")%>' />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgButtonStory" OnClientClick='displayStory();return false;' runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "UploadedImages/"+ Eval("Image") %>' 
                 CssClass="img-responsive img-rounded" />
            </div>    
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: `find('input[id$=txtID]')` =>`find('input[id=txtID]')` does it help?

Answer (score 0):

`this` doesn't not refers to element which invoked the click event handler, it refers to `window` object. You can use [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to set the context

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgButtonStory" OnClientClick='displayStory.call(this);return false;' runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "UploadedImages/"+ Eval("Image") %>' 
                         CssClass="img-responsive img-rounded" />
```

and in the script, You need to use `.prev()` as the text box is not child element of `ImageButton`

```
var txtIDValue= $(this).prev('input[id$=txtID]').val();
//var txtIDValue= $(this).closest('div').find('input[id$=txtID]').val();
```

Comment: you are a legend. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can simply say:

```
function displayStory() {
    var txtIDValue = $('input[id="txtID"]').val();
    var id = txtIDValue;
    alert(id);
}
```

`$('input[id="txtID"]')` will find the element `<input type="text" id="txtID" value='whatYouAreTryingToFind' />` and create a jQuery selector for it.

Tip:
In jQuery the scope of `$(this)` for events can be interesting, so always check exactly what it returns [Scope and this in JavaScript](https://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/).